# Calculate radius distance using cos/sin including if/then and inner join

Tags: sql, inner-join, trigonometry

**What i need:**

I need to write some kind of IF statement inside query to pick different coordinates, **if** `table1.business_id` is equal to `1`.

**For example:**

Pick `lng` and `lat` fields from `table1` **if** `table1.business_id = 1`, else, pick `lng` and `lat` fields from `table2`.

**Query:**

```
SELECT *, 
(3959 * acos(
   cos(radians('.$cords['result']['latitude'].')) * 
   cos(radians(lat)) * cos( radians(lng) - 
   radians('.$cords['result']['longitude'].')) + 
   sin(radians('.$cords['result']['latitude'].')) * 
   sin(radians(lat))
)) AS distance 
   FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.business_id 
   WHERE type <> "industry" AND '.$query.'
   HAVING distance < '.$radius.'
   ORDER BY distance LIMIT 100
```

How i can get this working? How to write technically correct query?

*Thanks for any answers.*

Comment: Try a `case` _expression_.

Comment: @jarlh some example would be awesome.

Comment: @Tauras: Its your duty to add examples :-). Kindly share sample data from both tables and we will help you adjust your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either a [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement, or an [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) statement to control the flow. The idea is to determine from which table to use the data so:

```
IF(`table1`.`business_id` = 1, `table1`.`lat`, `table2`.`lat`)
```

Would get put in place of all existing uses of `lat` (and the same for `long`)

```
SELECT *, 
(3959 * acos(
   cos(radians('.$cords['result']['latitude'].')) * 
   cos(radians(IF(`table1`.`business_id` = 1, `table1`.`lat`, `table2`.`lat`))) * 
   cos( radians(IF(`table1`.`business_id` = 1, `table1`.`lng`, `table2`.`lng`)) - 
   radians('.$cords['result']['longitude'].')) + 
   sin(radians('.$cords['result']['latitude'].')) * 
   sin(radians(IF(`table1`.`business_id` = 1, `table1`.`lat`, `table2`.`lat`)))
)) AS distance 
   FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.business_id 
   WHERE type <> "industry" AND '.$query.'
   HAVING distance < '.$radius.'
   ORDER BY distance LIMIT 100
```

Unrelated, it looks like you're concatenating values into your query. Be very careful that you're not opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks!

Comment: I will test your example now. I am not worried, because this one will be available for office only. Basically, localhost for 80 computers only.

Comment: Simply calculating cos(radians('.$cords['result']['latitude'] in php and just passing the result will filter out any attempts on that, and possibly save some time. The $query needs to be checked during building if contains user input. Many hacks come from disgruntled employees, so being inside is not an excuse not to make a habit of always using parameterized queries. And someday somebody may want to reuse that snippet for the public site.

Comment: @LeifNeland looks like that your if statement not working. Query does not pick results if business_id = 1 . I am still investigating.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that calculation with several conversions, cos and sin is rather heavy.

I'd suggest first selecting on a rectangle

```
where abs(latitude1-latitude2)<latdif
and abs(longitude1-longitude2)<longdif
```

Then use that in either a temporary table, a view, or a subquery.

This is of cause not a complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

'You can use case when

```
select a, b,
case 
  when table1.business_id = 1 
  then 'Pick lng and lat fields from table1'
  else 'pick lng and lat fields from table2' 
end col1, clo2
from table1, table 2 where table1.id = table2.id
```